# C Programming increment & decrement

Tags: c, post-increment

```
for(i=0;i++<10;)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
```

Why is it printing 1 to 10?

I know post increment happens after a loop, so why is it not showing 0? And why is it showing 10?

Comment: _"As i know post increment happens after a loop"_ Nope. The increment happens after the _statement_. `i++<10` is a single statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's label the elements of the loop:

```
for(/* 1 */ i=0; /* 2 */ i++<10; /* 4 */)
{
    /* 3 */ printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

Here's how things play out:

1. `i` is initialized to `0`;
2. The result of `i++` is compared to `10`; as a *side effect* of this expression, `i` is incremented by `1`;
3. The updated value of `i` is printed out;
4. If there were an expression here, it would be evaluated.

Steps 2 through 4 are repeated until `i++ < 10` evaluates to false.

Comment: So, when i++=10 ,the condition is false(i++<10).Then why it's printing the updated value of i as 10?

Comment: @AIN: Remember that the expression `i++` evaluates to the *current* value of `i`, and as a *side effect* adds 1 to `i`.  So, imagine `i` is set to `9`.  In the expression `i++<10`, `i++` evaluates to `9`, so the condition is true and the loop body is executed.  However, after the expression has been evaluated, `i` now has the value of `10`, and this is what gets printed out.  This is why the output ranges from `1` to `10`.

Comment: @AIN: Another way of writing this would be `for( i = 0; i < 10; ) { i++; printf("%d\n", i); }`

Answer (score 0):

No .. in for loop first condition is checked.. and after that you are printing `i` [image: For loop chart]

Comment: And in this case, it's the "test expression" step that increments i.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `do..while`

```
i=0;
do{
   printf("%d\n",i);
}while(i++<10);
```

Comment: Thanks but As per your do..while loop it's printing 0 to 10. And i need to know about the for loop explanation. @Pamblam